# understanding following javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have following javascript that I came across. I don't understand the process flow of the code execution.

```
var val = 'ap';

function func() {
    if (!val) {
        var val = 'ple';
    }
    console.log(val);
}
func();
console.log(val);
```

The output that I thought would be was, 'ap' then 'ap'.
But I get 'ple' and then 'ap'.
How is this happening?

Comment: although its wrong, you can use `window.val` instead of `val` inside your function, you have to understand that the scope of first `val` is `window` class and the second `val` is  in `func()` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `val` in the following line

```
var val = 'ple'
```

is getting hoisted to the top of the function.

The `val`s(inside the function) value is `undefined` which is *falsey* that is why the `if` condition is successful because `!false` is `true` and hence the `val` *inside* the function gets set to `'ple'`. It looks roughly like

```
function func()
   var val; // val = undefined
   if(!val) {  // it's still undefined and !undefined is true
      val = 'ple'; // so this code executes
   }
   console.log(val); // 'ple'
}
```

Remember that scope in javascript isn't block scope. Instead what you've to do is set the already declared `val`

```
val = 'ple';
```

Comment: If its a case of variable hoisting, why output is 'ple' and 'ap'. Output should be 'ple', 'ple' ?

Comment: @Kush `func` is called first and then `console.log(val)`

Comment: ok, so you mean val declared & defined at the top is not visible to func() ? Now am getting it.

Comment: yes.. sort of.. the `val` inside the function is overshadowing the one which is outside

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has functional scope and not block scope until we get the let statement in ES6...